# Закрытие консольного приложения

Tags: c#, консоль

Всем привет. Скажите, как можно отлавливать событие клика по крестику в консольном приложении?

Comment: Очень странный вопрос. А если крестика вообще нет?

Comment: Он есть у всех приложений... Вверху справа.

Comment: и у консолных? Жаль мунусовать пока не могу:(

Comment: Вопрос поставлен неправильно. Автор, видимо, имел ввиду обработку сигнала закрытия консольного приложения "извне" (будь то "крестик", если консоль запущена в оконной среде, либо что-то ещё). Формулируйте вопрос корректно, телепатов здесь нету :)

Comment: Какого типа HandleConsoleError; где  и как его объявлять

Answer (score 10):

В классе System.Console есть событие [CancelKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx), однако оно срабатывает только для комбинаций клавиш **Ctrl+C** и **Ctrl+Break** - стандартные хоткеи для закрытия консольного приложения.

Если требуется отлавливать все сигналы закрытия приложения (Закрытие окна консоли, выхода пользователя из системы, или выключения системы), то можно использовать WinAPI функцию [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx), предварительно импортировав её из kernel32.dll. Также нужно будет описать несколько констант, описание которых можно найти на [этой странице](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx), и делегат для вашего callback-метода.

```
internal delegate void SignalHandler(ConsoleSignal consoleSignal);

internal enum ConsoleSignal
{
    CtrlC = 0,
    CtrlBreak = 1,
    Close = 2,
    LogOff = 5,
    Shutdown = 6
}

internal static class ConsoleHelper
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "SetConsoleCtrlHandler")]
    public static extern bool SetSignalHandler(SignalHandler handler, bool add);
}
```

Для закрытия окна консоли параметр `consoleSignal` будет иметь значение `ConsoleSignal.Close`. Использовать это можно, например, так:

```
public sealed class Program
{
    private static SignalHandler signalHandler;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            signalHandler += HandleConsoleSignal;
            ConsoleHelper.SetSignalHandler(signalHandler, true);

            // ...
    }

    private static void HandleConsoleSignal(ConsoleSignal consoleSignal)
    {
        // TO DO
    }
}
```

По собственному опыту скажу, что для обработки такого сигнала выделяется всего несколько секунд, поэтому не стоит в обработчике выполнять лишних действий.

Comment: Какого типа HandleConsoleError; Как и где его определить?

Comment: Вместо него должен быть HandleConsoleSignal. Спасибо за замечание, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего вам необходимо обрабатывать `Environment.Exit` или `Application.Exit`.

У консольного приложения нет крестика, на то оно и консольное. Если вы запускаете приложение в консоли, то крестик есть у самой консоли, а не у вашего приложения.