# Как реализовать вызов функции при закрытии консольного приложения?(передать в делегат переменную)

Tags: c#

Взял код отсюда ([Закрытие консольного приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174216))
Но я хочу так же добавить, чтобы пользователь в начале программы вводил какое-либо число, и затем это число отображалось в MessageBox.
То есть что-то типо:

```
private static void doAtClosing(ConsoleSignal consoleSignal,int returnValue)
{
    MessageBox.Show(consoleSignal.ToString()+returnValue.ToString());
}
```

Но как передать число в эту функцию(как returnValue) при вызове из функции Main к примеру?

Answer (score 0):

Используя код по Вашей ссылке, получаем:

```
    public sealed class Program
    {
    private static SignalHandler signalHandler;

    private static int num = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            signalHandler += HandleConsoleSignal;
            ConsoleHelper.SetSignalHandler(signalHandler, true);

            num = Console.Read();
    }

    private static void HandleConsoleSignal(ConsoleSignal consoleSignal)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(consoleSignal.ToString() + num.ToString());
    }
}
```

У меня нет компилятора, поэтому проверить правильность решения я не могу.

Comment: А можно ли как то добавить задержку перед закрытием программы? Чтобы она успела выполнить функцию

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант - это заставить поток ожидать какое-то время. Подключите Threading, добавив в код строку: using System.Threading;      А далее добавить строчку в тело метода Main:   Thread.Sleep(1000);  , где вместо 1000 подойдет любое время, измеряемое в миллисекундах